# sorting an array of pairs according to a comparing function C++

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of pairs `(i,j)` in a way that `if (i.first > j.first)` then `i` comes first, `if (i.first == j.first)` then `i.second` must be less than `j.second` in order to come first, here's the function I wrote but it doesn't seem to be working

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool cmp(pair<int,int> i, pair<int,int> j) {
    if(i.first > j.first)
        return i<j;
    else if (i.first == j.first) {
        if(i.second > j.second)
            return i < j;
        else
            return j<i;
    }
    else
        return j<i;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pair<int,int> arr[4];
    arr[0]=make_pair<int,int>(3,7);
    arr[1]=make_pair<int,int>(2,5);
    arr[2]=make_pair<int,int>(3,4);
    arr[3]=make_pair<int,int>(1,8);
    sort(arr,arr+3,cmp);
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        printf("element (%d,%d)\n",get<0>(arr[i]),get<1>(arr[i]));
    }
}
```

The sorting function doesn't seem to work:

```
$ g++ -o main main.cpp
$ ./main
element (3,7)
element (2,5)
element (3,4)
element (1,8)
```

Any ideas? Thanks for reading

Comment: What are you trying to do in that messy function? Looks like a set of random statements

Comment: @Slava i'm trying to sort them so that if i.first > j.first then i comes first in the array, in the case that i.first == j.first then it compares between i.second and j.second, if i.second < j.second then i comes first in the array, and vice versa, sorry it's a little messy

Comment: The comparator needs to define a strict weak ordering   (e.g.. if a < b and b < c then a < c is always true) Your function does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
bool cmp(pair<int,int> i, pair<int,int> j)
{
    if( i.first == j.first ) 
        return i.second < j.second;
    return i.first > j.first;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might rely on default order of pair/tuple and so adjust your input:

```
bool cmp(pair<int,int> lhs, pair<int,int> rhs) {
    return std::make_pair(-lhs.first, lhs.second)
         < std::make_pair(-rhs.first, rhs.second);
}
```

or

```
bool cmp(pair<int,int> lhs, pair<int,int> rhs) {
    return std::tie(rhs.first, lhs.second)
         < std::tie(lhs.first, rhs.second);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool cmp(std::pair<int, int> i, std::pair<int, int> j)
{
    if(i.first > j.first)
    {
        // now i IS greater than j, so just:
        return true;
    }

    // you returned, so you can only get here if the condition was not met;
    // some consider still using else bad style...

    else if (i.first == j.first)
    {
        // don't ever use if(condition) return true; else return false;
        // just do:       return condition;
        // so:
        return i.second > j.second;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can have it just a little shorter:

```
bool greater(std::pair<int, int> i, std::pair<int, int> j)
{
    if(i.first == j.first)
    {
        return i.second < j.second;
    }
    return i.first > j.first;
}
```

or even as one-liner:

```
return i.first == j.first ? i.second < j.second : i.first > j.first;
```

Finally, you could use a lambda as well (if you sort in this specific order at just one single location):

```
std::sort
(
    a, a + n,
    [](std::pair<int,int> i, std::pair<int,int> j)
    {
        return i.first == j.first ? i.second < j.second : i.first > j.first;
    }
);
```

At the very end explaining your original code:

```
if(i.first > j.first)
    // std::pair's comparison operator will exactly do the analog
    // stuff you INTENDED to do, but now, as the "first"s already
    // compare greater, i < j will return just the opposite,
    // i. e. false(!!!)
    return i < j;
```

Analogously all the other comparisons, so your it was equivalent to:

```
bool cmp(std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int>)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You got second condition wrong, if that the case then just `i > j` would work

Comment: It was my first time sorting using a comparing function, this made the concept alot more clear to me, thank you